# How to add an HTML tag to the value of an array?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

This is my HTML code. Here I render all the elements in the array (which is in the `state`) and add a class `"dragImg"` to each element (I need this class for another use). Under the rendered array, I have an `input` and `button`; the idea is that the user can type something and when he clicks on the `button`, the input text gets added to the array in the `state`.

```
 <div>
    {this.state.texts.map(text => (
         <div class="dragImg">{text}</div>
     ))}
 </div>
 <input ref={(textInput) => {this.textInput = textInput}} 
 type="text"></input>
 <button onClick={this.clickButton.bind(this)}>Add 
 Text</button>
```

Here is the `clickButton()` function where the input value gets added to the state:

```
clickButton(){

        this.setState({
            texts: this.state.texts.concat(this.textInput.value)
          }) 
          
    }
```

All the elements of the list get rendered correctly, the problem is that only the predefined elements in the list get the `"dragImg"` HTML class tag and the ones that get added later on by the user don't have it anymore. This is a problem for me, because I want all these texts to be draggable, and only the elements which have the `"dragImg"` class tag are draggable and the new inputs aren't.

What can I do?

Comment: Why do you need a `ref` to access input value? Why not just keep it in a state?

Answer (score 0):

use **ClassName** instead of **class** in react js

and best practice is to handle the typing value using state.

```
<input 
    value={ this.state.fieldInput } 
    onchange= { (e) => { this.setState({ fieldInput: event.target.value }); } } 
>
```

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't solve my problem.